# How to log session ID in weblogic's access log

Tags: java, logging, weblogic, sessionid

Is it possible to log the session ID in the access log of WebLogic 8.1.6?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using [Extended Log Format](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/adminguide/web_server.html#100418) and [Custom Field Identifiers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/adminguide/web_server.html#107398). I'm providing a Java implementation of a custom field printing the session ID below. Follow the steps of the 2nd link to setup the whole solution. Adapt the fully-qualified name as per your preferences.

```
import weblogic.servlet.logging.CustomELFLogger;
import weblogic.servlet.logging.FormatStringBuffer;
import weblogic.servlet.logging.HttpAccountingInfo;

/** 
 * Outputs the session ID specified by the client into a custom field called MyCustomField
 */
public class MyCustomField implements CustomELFLogger {

    public void logField(HttpAccountingInfo metrics, FormatStringBuffer buff) {
        buff.appendValueOrDash(metrics.getRequestedSessionId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Just updating newer doc info : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13701/web_server.htm#i1066198